# how to Change Uploaded Product image disabled value

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I uploaded product image programatically by using following code.

```
$files = $_FILES['images']['name'];
$f = substr($files,0,1);
$s= substr($files,1,1);
$absolute_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'catalog'.DS.'product'.DS.$f.DS.$s; 
if(isset($files) && $files != '') 
{   
    try 
    { 
          if(file_exists($absolute_path.DS.$files)) 
          { 
               $var = rand(0,99); 
               $files = $var.'_'.$files; 
          } 
          // Starting upload 
          $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('images'); 
          //Here 4 extention would work 
          $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); 
          $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false); 
          //false -> get the file directly in the specified folder 
          //true -> get the file in the product like folders /media/catalog/product/file.gif 
          $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false); 
          //We set media as the upload dir 
          $uploader->save($absolute_path, $files);

    } 
    catch(Exception $e) 
    { 
          Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage()); 
    } 

$absolute_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'catalog'.DS.'product'.DS.$f.DS.$s.DS.$files;

$mediaArray = array(
        'thumbnail'   => $absolute_path,
        'small_image' => $absolute_path,
        'image'       => $absolute_path,
    );
    foreach($mediaArray as $imageType => $files)
    {
        $filePath = $files;
        if(file_exists($filePath)) 
        {
            try
            {
             $product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false);
            } 
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Product does not have an image or the path is incorrect. Path was: {$filePath}<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

It is added in backend but in the table

> ***catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value***

uploaded images disabled column value is 1.

If I upload image from backend, the uploaded image disabled column value is set as 0.
How to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addImageToMediaGallery` method accepts a fourth argument (*exclude* - a boolean) that sets the image to enabled or disabled. It defaults to true, which means exclude from the gallery/disabled.

Change your code to

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, $imageType, false, false);
```

Also, I don't think you need to loop through $mediaArray to create each size you can call the method once like

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery(
    $filePath,
    array('thumbnail', 'small_image', 'image'), 
    false, 
    false
 );
```